# Change the input value via jQuery when image uploaded [uploadify]

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I am using uploadify, everything works but i want to change my hidden input value to uploaded filename once it gets uploaded. There are 5 image, i am uploading at a time, and i want to append them one after one.

```
<input type="file" id="file_upload" name="file_upload" />
<input type="hidden" name="image1" id="image1" />
<input type="hidden" name="image2" id="image5" />
<input type="hidden" name="image3" id="image3" />
<input type="hidden" name="image4" id="image4" />
<input type="hidden" name="image5" id="image5" />
```

and this is my uploadify script :-

```
<?php $timestamp = time();?>
            $(function() {
            $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
            'auto'             : false,
            'multi'             : true,
            'fileType'     : 'image',
            'queueSizeLimit' : 5,
            'formData'         : {
                   'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
            'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
            },
            'queueID'          : 'queue',
            'uploadScript'     : 'uploadifive.php',
            'onUploadComplete' : function(file, data) { 
alert('The File ' + file.name + " has been uploaded");}
        });
});
```

Once upload has completed, I want to change all `hidden` input field with respective images name.

something like :-

`$("$image1").attr('src', file.name);`

but one by one to all ? How can i do them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `.appendTo()` or `.html()` in `jQuery`, so instead of having the hidden values above, use a div and append to the div as they load...

```
<div id="images"></aid>
```

build your html..

```
$("#images").html('<img src="' + file.name+ '" />');
```

...or...

```
$("#images").appendTo('<img src="' + file.name+ '" />');
```

Comment: OK, well it might be useful down the line for others that come across the post :)

Comment: `$('#images').attr('src', file.name);` & `$('#images').val(file.name);` did a better job for my solution :)

Comment: How did you target the individual hidden fields though?

Comment: `$('#images').val(file.name);`